# Limit UmbracoAuthorizedController to Umbraco Admin Users Only

Tags: c#, authorization, umbraco, umbraco8

I have create a new controller, inherited from the `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoAuthorizedController` and trying to limit it to only logged in **Umbraco Administrators**.

My current solution displays the view for only logged in umbraco users, but I cannot filter for only admins.

**Code:**

I have a Composer and I set up the route config:

```
public class ApplicationEventComposer : IComposer
{
    public void Compose(Composition composition)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ITTest",
            url: "umbraco/backoffice/ITTest/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "ITTest", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        composition.Register<ITTestController>(Lifetime.Request);
    }
}
```

I have a controller:

```
public class ITTestController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoAuthorizedController
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       return View("/Views/ITTest/Index.cshtml");
   }
}
```

I have tried to add different attributes to filter for only adminsitrators like:

```
[UmbracoAuthorize(Roles = "admin")]
[UmbracoApplicationAuthorize(Roles = "admin")]
[AdminUsersAuthorize]
```

And tried different roles like "admin", "administrator", "administrators", "Administrators" etc. but nothing seems to work.

(Side note: At the moment I am thinking about a workaround and overwrite the `OnAuthorization` event, but that would be more of a hack than a proper solution.)

**Questions:**

- How can I filter the users using Umbraco roles?
- What are the role names exactly? Are they the user group names or something else?

**Update:**

*(I tried to improve the answer below, but it was rejected, so I will add my findings here)*

The `[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]` one is working!

I was playing around with it. To make it work it still needs to be under "umbraco/backoffice", but it does not have to be a `UmbracoAuthorizedController` it seems to be working fine when it is (only) `RenderMvcController`

The built in role names are:

- "admin"
- "sensitiveData"
- "translator"
- "writer"
- "editor"

For more info: https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/99651-limit-umbracoauthorizedcontroller-to-umbraco-admin-users-only#comment-313527

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UmbracoAuthorizedController` controller effectively just adds the `UmbracoAuthorize` attribute to your controller, but it seems this attribute ignores any roles you pass in, and just checks the visitor is an authenticated back-office user.

You can see this in detail in the `AuthorizeCore` method in:

https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/853087a75044b814df458457dc9a1f778cc89749/src/Umbraco.Web/Mvc/UmbracoAuthorizeAttribute.cs

and the `ValidateRequestAttempt` method in:

https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/853087a75044b814df458457dc9a1f778cc89749/src/Umbraco.Web/Security/WebSecurity.cs

This isn't what I would have expected!

To achieve what you require you could inherit from the `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoController` controller and decorate it with a standard MVC `Authorize` attribute.

I've successfully tested the following in Umbraco 8.2.0:

```cs
    public class ITTestController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoController
    {
        [Authorize(Roles = "someGroup")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("/Views/ITTest/Index.cshtml");
        }
    }
```

where `someGroup` is the Umbraco group you wish to allow.

Comment: Thanks, That's what I have also figured out. The role should be "admin".
https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/99651-limit-umbracoauthorizedcontroller-to-umbraco-admin-users-only#comment-313527

Answer (score -1):

Umbraco documentation:

https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Implementation/Controllers/

suggests you should use the `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoAuthorizeAttribute` attribute, which I think you've tried, so I would just update the Roles to be `Roles = "Administrators"`, so you have something like:

```cs
[UmbracoAuthorize(Roles = "Administrators")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View("/Views/ITTest/Index.cshtml");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote I have tried it. Any user logged in to umbraco can access the page, admin or not.

Comment: What version of Umbraco are you using?

Comment: Umbraco version 8.1.1